# How to manipulate highlighted text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a WYSIWYG HTML Editor. right now we can align text to left, center, and right. I want to add if user highlights some text and click on bold or italic button. I want to make it bold.

I am getting the highlighted text like so

```
const getHighlightedText = () => {
  let text = '';
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (
    document.selection &&
    document.selection.type != 'Control'
  ) {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
};
```

Now how can I add the text inside strong or em tags. I thought of using string replace. but it won't correctly if we have same text multiple times.

How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const getHighlightedText = () => {
    let text = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (
      document.selection &&
      document.selection.type != 'Control'
    ) {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
  };

  let activeElement = null;

  $('#builder-content').on('click', (e) => {
    activeElement = $(e.target);
    console.log(activeElement);
  });

  $('#builder-align-text-left').on('click', (e) => {
    if (activeElement.hasClass('text-end')) {
      $(activeElement).removeClass('text-end');
    }
    if (activeElement.hasClass('text-center')) {
      $(activeElement).removeClass('text-center');
    }

    activeElement.addClass('text-start');
  });

  $('#builder-align-text-left').on('click', (e) => {
    if (activeElement.hasClass('text-end')) {
      $(activeElement).removeClass('text-end');
    }
    if (activeElement.hasClass('text-center')) {
      $(activeElement).removeClass('text-center');
    }

    activeElement.addClass('text-start');
  });

  $('#builder-align-text-center').on('click', (e) => {
    if (activeElement.hasClass('text-end')) {
      $(activeElement).removeClass('text-end');
    }
    if (activeElement.hasClass('text-start')) {
      $(activeElement).removeClass('text-start');
    }

    activeElement.addClass('text-center');
  });

  $('#builder-align-text-right').on('click', (e) => {
    if (activeElement.hasClass('text-center')) {
      $(activeElement).removeClass('text-center');
    }
    if (activeElement.hasClass('text-start')) {
      $(activeElement).removeClass('text-start');
    }

    $(activeElement).addClass('text-end');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-OLYO0LymqQ+uHXELyx93kblK5YIS3B2ZfLGBmsJaUyor7CpMTBsahDHByqSuWW+q" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body p-4">
          <div id="builder-editor">
            <div id="builder-content" contenteditable="true">
              <h3>Heading 3</h3>
              <p>
                In JavaScript, when an object is passed to a function expecting a string (like window.alert() or document.write()), the object's toString() method is called and the returned value is passed to the function. This can make the object appear to be a string
                when used with other functions when it is really an object with properties and methods.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="d-flex builder-toolbar">
            <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none me-3">
                  <i class="fas fa-bold"></i>
                </button>
            <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none me-3">
                  <i class="fas fa-italic"></i>
                </button>
            <button id="builder-align-text-left" class="btn btn-light shadow-none me-3">
                  <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                </button>
            <button id="builder-align-text-center" class="btn btn-light shadow-none me-3">
                  <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
                </button>
            <button id="builder-align-text-right" class="btn btn-light shadow-none me-3">
                  <i class="fas fa-align-right"></i>
                </button>
            <button id="builder-align-text-right" class="btn btn-light shadow-none me-3">
                  <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
                </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add **strong** tag on click event for bold button like below :

```
<button class="btn btn-light shadow-none me-3" id="builder-text-bold">
   <i class="fas fa-bold"></i>
</button>

  $('#builder-text-bold').on('click', (e) => {
    var range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    } else if (document.selection) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
    }

    if (range != null && range != '' ) {
       var newNode = $('<strong>  </strong>')[0];
       range.surroundContents(newNode);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to check if strong tag is already added or not?

Comment: I think you want to remove strong tag when user clicks on B again or if he selects text which is already bold and you want to remove it. For that you can use extractContent like below

   var bold = document.createElement('b');
    var text = range;
    bold.innerHTML = range;
    range.extractContents(); 
And if you want to remove only tags then this extractContents returns the node element so you can manipulate it and insert it again using insertNode. This link describes selection and range appropriately  
https://javascript.info/selection-range#range